# How do I need to modify my WinForms app to also run in the console?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, console

I have a .NET WinForms app written in C#. In order to support batch operations, I'd now like to make the app able to run in the console.

Is it possible to have an app that detects on startup whether it is running in the console or not?

What modifications do I need to make in order to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: support batch operations? do you mean run batch files? If so, look into processstartinfo: http://www.debugging.com/bug/9625 . I have run batch files from windows services, windows apps, console apps, it don't matter where you is, it matters what permies you got.

Comment: The main reason is that my GUI allows the user to make changes before running, in batch mode, I want it to get on with it.

Comment: If your objects need to understand that you are in console or GUI, you can set a global variable. Better yet, you can have GUI and Console specific classes implimenting an interface or inheriting from a base class or both depending on your application's structure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have a Program.cs file in your solution, this file contains a:

```
static void Main() 
{
}
```

You'll notice in this method there is something like:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

This is where your form is actually launched, so what you can do is modify your `Main()` to something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   if(args.Length < 1)
   {
      Application.Run(new Form1());
      return;
   }
   else
   {
     // Handle your command line arguments and do work
   }
}
```

So if your program is invoked with no command line arguments, the windows form pops open and does its thing.  Otherwise you do what you need to do via the command line and exit without ever showing a form.

Answer (score 2):

You can allocate a Console for your WinForms app using the [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. You can find more information about how to call this from C# on it's pinvoke [page](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.allocconsole).

However, this will not make it a true console app and I've heard that there are some limitations, however, it might work depending on your exact needs.

Comment: If you're interested in allocating a console from a Windows Forms application, you'll probably be interested in my ConsoleDotNet wrapper: mischel.com/pubs/consoledotnet/consoledotnet.zip.  I wrote this up for DevSource a few years ago.  Two of the three articles are still available.  Unfortunately, the first article (which explains setting things up) has gone missing.

Comment: I'm not sure why I'd need to allocate a console: what I want to do is run my app *from* a console.

Comment: @tom: I read your question as you want to interact with a console, so that your app wants to write things back to the console and maybe let the user (or other process) send commands to it via the console. If all you want is to accept some commandline arguments and run without showing a form, then Coding Gorilla's answer is better.

Comment: Though thinking about it, `AttachConsole` would probably have been a more suitable alternative than `AllocConsole` for my answer.

Comment: @ho1: The problem with `AttachConsole` is that there has to be a console available and you have to know how to locate it.  And if somebody closes the console while you're attached to it, your program goes away (unless you do some magic).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a main method in program.cs and detect whether command line parameters are passed in, if they are do batch processing, if not show the GUI.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
 if (args.count > 0) {
  //batch
 } else {
  //gui
 }

}
```

Comment: The static main method is already there.  You just need to add the conditional processing.